# All continents and their most used currency

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following database:

[image]

I am trying to write a query that finds all **continents** and their **most-used currency** and filter any currency that is used in **only one country**. I first tried to see how many times each currency code is used:

```
SELECT c.CurrencyCode, 
       COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Countries AS c
GROUP BY c.CurrencyCode
```

I think this code is working fine. Let me show you what I want to select:

- **ContinentCode**
- **CurrencyCode**
- **CurrencyUsage**

> ```
> ContinentCode CurrencyCode    CurrencyUsage
> AF                XOF             8
> AS                AUD             2
> AS                ILS             2
> EU                EUR             26
> NA                XCD             8
> OC                USD             8
> ```

Thank you in advance! I guess we should have a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you need only Currency code and Continent code, you can fetch all this info from one table `Countries`, so no real need for joins here.

I understand the "most-used currency" as a currency that is used in most number of countries on that continent.

I don't understand what "filter any currency that is used in only one country" means, so I ignored this sentence.

At first, `GROUP BY ContinentCode, CurrencyCode` to get the count of countries that use this currency, for each continent

```
SELECT
    ContinentCode, CurrencyCode, COUNT(*) AS UseCount
FROM Countries
GROUP BY ContinentCode, CurrencyCode
```

Now, we need to get one, most used currency for each continent. It is a `top-n-per-group` problem. One variant is to use `ROW_NUMBER` function.

I'll use CTEs (common-table expressions) to make the query readable.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ContinentCode, CurrencyCode, COUNT(*) AS UseCount
    FROM Countries
    GROUP BY ContinentCode, CurrencyCode
)
,CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        ContinentCode, CurrencyCode, UseCount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContinentCode ORDER BY UseCount DESC, CurrencyCode) AS rn
    FROM CTE
    WHERE UseCount > 1
)
SELECT
    ContinentCode, CurrencyCode, UseCount
FROM CTE_rn
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

I added `CurrencyCode` in the `ORDER BY` to resolve possible ties. If there is more than one currency that is used in the same number of countries on a continent, they will get the same `UseCount`. In this case the query selects one currency based on their `CurrencyCode`.

Comment: Thank you for the response! By saying 'filter any currency that is used in only one country', I mean that we should only show the currencies where `UseCount` > 1.

Comment: @Vladimir You do not need the 2nd CTE, just use the FIRST_VALUE function, instead of ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: @keylin.rion, I've added `WHERE UseCount > 1` to the query, but results would most likely be the same, unless you have a continent that has a set of countries that all use different languages, i.e. `UseCount` for all languages on the continent is `1`. Hmm. Maybe Australia. It has 1 country and 1 language, so it will be removed from the results.

Comment: @RobertCo, `FIRST_VALUE` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` by itself is not enough. You need to pick only one row from each group somehow. This is done by `WHERE rn = 1`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, see the example. I did it with `DENSE_RANK`. When two currencies have equal usage, we should show both of them.

Comment: @keylin.rion, yes, `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` is a good choice in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is the list of Currencies that are used in more than one country, you can use `having`:

```
SELECT c.CurrencyCode, 
       COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Countries AS c
GROUP BY c.CurrencyCode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```